# inline css not print in email when send email through php mail

Tags: php, html, css, email

Hello all i am tring to sending email through email function in php but before send i email and echo body of the email it is display well what i need but this body sent in mail it is some css not working. i have attached two images (screenshorts) one is before send email and second after i geting email and you will understand properly.

```
$body.= '<table border=1><tr><th>Branch</th>';
            for($i=0;$i<count($sections);$i++)
            {
                if($sections[$i]!="Task Admin")
                $body.="<th>".$sections[$i]."</th>";
            }
            $body.="</tr>";
            foreach($mainarrayparent as $keys => $value ) {
            $body.="<tr>";
                foreach($value as $keys1 => $getbranch ) { 
                    $getb = mysql_query("SELECT * from branch where id = '".$keys1."'");
                    $getbrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getb);

                    $body.="<td>".$keys1." - ".$getbrow['name']."</td>";
                    foreach($getbranch as $keys3 => $getinner ) {
                            if($getinner==0){
                            $body.="<td style='background-color:#C6EFCE;'>".$getinner."</td>";
                            }else if($getinner!=0){
                            $body.="<td style='background-color:#FFC7CE;'>".$getinner."</td>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo $keys3;

                            }
                    }   
                }
                $body.="</tr>";
            }
                $body.="</table>";
            //#C6EFCE
            echo $body;
            // die;

    //get overdue 


    $subject = "Acquisition Updates";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <intranet@daylewis.net>' . "\r\n"; 
    $result = mail('jignesh.prajapati@daylewisplc.co.uk',$subject,$body,$headers);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check the HTML of these cells via Inspect element via Developer Tools on Chrome or any such equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm, I might know this one. I remember that some email programs have issues with long bits of text. Placing returns and cutting up the html which might cause problems. Adding a return or a `PHP_EOL` to the end of some of those loops might help.

```
 foreach ($getbranch as $keys3 => $getinner) {
    if ($getinner == 0) {
        $body .= "<td style='background-color:#C6EFCE;'>" . $getinner . "</td>" . PHP_EOL;
    } else if ($getinner != 0) {
        $body .= "<td style='background-color:#FFC7CE;'>" . $getinner . "</td>" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $keys3;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's one of those where you 'just have to know' otherwise it could cause issues.